# Правильный подход ООП PHP

Tags: php

Недавно познакомился с ООП, в целом вещь довольно полезная. Не до конца понимаю как правильно это дело использовать. У меня все действия описаны в классах, остаются только управляющие функции. Посмотрел на чужой код, оказалось все не так, часто ООП юзают в 'перемешку' c процедурным стилем. Какой из этих подходов является правильным? И еще вопрос, есть такие вещи как свойства, их нужно перечислять в начале класса. Но это не удобно, писать название свойств на две страницы часто напрягает. Конечно можно без этого, тогда по умолчанию поставиться модификатор public, а что если мне нужен private?

Comment: Если у вас _свойств на две страницы_, не лучше ли их объединить в одно свойство-массив?

Comment: @hindmost, Не думаю, что хорошая идея. Например, есть свойство, и я хочу в IDE найти все случаи его использования (частая практика) - если это будет массив - мне придется искать по использованию всего массива?

Comment: Если у вас очень много свойств, то, возможно, вам стоит поделить класс на несколько. В моей практике очень редко получается так, что у класса больше десяти свойств, даже когда туда нужно напихать менеджеры блокировок, кэша, базы данных и исполнителя задач.

Comment: @A1essandro Не думаю, что без контекста можно судить хорошая эта идея или нет. Все же использование массива для хранения свойств не такая уж редкая практика. Иначе [методы перегрузки](http://fi2.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.overloading.php) были бы бесполезны.

Comment: @hindmost, я не говорил, что это редкая практика. Я говорю (возможно, это только мое личное мнение) - что за таким кодом труднее следить. Это совершенно разное, следить за прозрачно объявленным свойством, или за ключами массива свойства. Для того, чтобы можно было уследить и за ними, лучше объявлять их константами, т.е. все равно сначала нужно жестко задать список ключей такого массива, чтобы код был более прост в поддержке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пойдем по порядку.

Как правильно использовать ООП - это тема на целую книгу. Вам нужно больше читать на эту тему, и конечно же - практика.

По поводу процедурного кода 'вперемешку'. Это смотря какой код Вы смотрели. Если Вы взгляните на большие фреймворки типа Symfony2/3 или Yii2 - вряд ли сходу найдете процедурный стиль. В CMS а-ля Joomla (старые версии точно), Drupal 7 - там будет целый набор функций, с малым количеством классов. Вообще, ООП - это удобно, но, в случае малых данных - забирает лишние ресурсы. Скажем так - если Вам нужно посчитать `2 * 2` - то нет смысла объявлять класс (очень утрированно). Но если Вы создаете большую систему - без них будет очень тяжело (и без типов данных, перейдя на строготипизированный язык, я понял весь смак строгих типов в огромных системах).

По поводу свойств:

1. Если не будете объявлять свойства в классе, а во внешнем коде (через присваивания `obj.newPropery = value` - это не правильно. Код будет непрозрачным. Назначение классов и свойств в нем тоже. Вообще уследить за использованием таких свойств труднее. Лучше все же объявлять. К тому же сразу можно задать строки документации.
2. Если у Вас в классе over9000 свойств - нужно задуматься, а не разбить ли этот класс на несколько? Используя композицию или наследование, или что-то, что нибудь, что Вам заблагорассудится.

По поводу громоздкости описаний свойств: ИМХО - это норма. Если Вы работаете в PhpStorm - можете использовать `#region RegionName` как открывающую регион строку, и `#endregion` как закрывающую, чтобы скрывать по требованию 'регион' между этими строками. Лично меня больше даже, напрягают строки `use NameSpace;`, которые несут в себе мало полезной информации (в отличие от полезной функции), но занимают иногда очень много места.

Comment: @Filipp Mustang Если вы уж выбрали ответ как решение, было бы неплохо и поощрить его плюсом (репутации у вас достаточно).